# Best way to do an if else block using values within Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

Am trying to do an if else statement using the on("keydown") function in JQuery.

Essentially am trying to alter the HTML depending on whether a particular key within a set group is pressed.

Here is the code:

```
     keyCodeToChar = {8:"Backspace",9:"Tab",13:"Enter",16:"Shift",17:"Ctrl",18:"Alt",19:"Pause/Break",20:"Caps Lock",27:"Esc",32:"Space",33:"Page Up",34:"Page Down",35:"End",36:"Home",37:"Left",38:"Up",39:"Right",40:"Down",45:"Insert",46:"Delete",48:"0",49:"1",50:"2",51:"3",52:"4",53:"5",54:"6",55:"7",56:"8",57:"9",65:"A",66:"B",67:"C",68:"D",69:"E",70:"F",71:"G",72:"H",73:"I",74:"J",75:"K",76:"L",77:"M",78:"N",79:"O",80:"P",81:"Q",82:"R",83:"S",84:"T",85:"U",86:"V",87:"W",88:"X",89:"Y",90:"Z"};

    var letter = keyCodeToChar[e.which || e.keyCode];

    document.getElementById(letter).play();

    var cool_letters = ["L","E","M","Z"];

    if ($.inArray(letter, cool_letters) == true) {

        var myHtml = "<p class='" + letter + "''>" + letter + "</p>";

        $('.key').append(myHtml)
                 .css("display", "block")
                 .css("color", random_colour);

    } else {

        var myHtml = letter;

        $('.key').append(myHtml)
                 .css("display", "block")
                 .css("color", random_colour);

    };
```

For some reason, no matter what I try, I can't get the JS to recognise the individual letters in var cool_letters, and enact the if... else block correctly. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Now edited to remove the typo.

Comment: had a problem with the formatting... removed a lot of the unnecessary  parts of the array eg backspace keycode etc

Comment: var letter returns the letter as desired

Comment: Still, safer and far more reliable to use the key codes for comparison...

Comment: Sorry guys, copy pasted the wrong array as you pointed out. Now edited.

Comment: Next time, please start with http://fiddle.net - it'll be more productive.

Comment: You're simply using the [wrong method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) (or using it incorrectly)... That one returns an index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i stated in my comment the [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns an index, which is why your method fails... You could still use the method, but compare like `!=-1`...

Comment: That was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The following is obsolete after the corrected code has been pasted.

---

I don't know if it's *the* problem, but *a* problem that will keep this from working is that `letter` will *never* evaluate to one of the strings being looked for.

This is because the Map (object) goes from *letter* -> *character code* and not *character code* -> *letter*.

Either fix the Map (the numeric values should be keys) or eliminate the Map entirely with some math.